# JS scripts doesn't work in partial view after it refreshed

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, .net

**Problem:** partialview contains js scripts, when they are first loaded, they work. After the second loading, js scripts stop working.

**Desc:** I have partial view reload on value change on selectbox (this calls this function)

```
@(Html
        .DevExtreme()
        .SelectBox()
        .ID("id_sb_year")
        .DataSource(d =&gt; d
            .Mvc()
            .Controller("Ecp")
            .LoadAction("WezRok")
            .Key("Rok")
        )
        .DisplayExpr("Rok")
        .ValueExpr("Rok")
        .SearchEnabled(true)
        .OnValueChanged("pobierzTabele")
                        )
```

```
@(Html
        .DevExtreme()
        .SelectBox()
        .ID("id_sb_month")
        .DataSource(d =&gt; d
            .Mvc()
            .Controller("Ecp")
            .LoadAction("WezMiesiac")
            .Key("Miesiac")
        )
        .DisplayExpr("DescMiesiac")
        .ValueExpr("Miesiac")
        .SearchEnabled(true)
        .OnValueChanged("pobierzTabele")
                        )
```

Two values ​​from two selectboxes must be selected for the function to work

```
function pobierzTabele() {

 var numerMiesiaca = $("#id_sb_month").dxSelectBox("instance").option("value")
    var numerRoku = $("#id_sb_year").dxSelectBox("instance").option("value")

    if (numerMiesiaca != null && numerRoku != null) {

        function daysInMonth(month, year) {
            return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        }

        var liczbaDni = daysInMonth(numerMiesiaca, numerRoku);


        var userDate = {
             numerMiesiaca: $("#id_sb_month").dxSelectBox("instance").option("value"),
             numerRoku: $("#id_sb_year").dxSelectBox("instance").option("value"),
             liczbaDni: liczbaDni
         };

 $.ajax({

            url: "@Url.Action("PartialTabelaEcp", "Home")",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {"userDate": JSON.stringify(userDate)},
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                $("#kartaEcp").html(data);


            },
            failure: function (error) {
                alert(error);

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**effect:** throws this partialview in this place

```
   <div class="kartaEcp" name="kartaEcp" id="kartaEcp">
        </div>
```

**partial view:**

```
@using AppEcp.Models
@model ParentView



@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "tableForm" }))
{
  <table><table>
}

<script src="~/js/tabela/Arkusz.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/tabela/halfStartEnd.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/tabela/minimumEnds.js"></script>
```

**Nowadays:** I need to refresh the page to be able to select the value again and load the partialview again, which is unacceptable

I found sth this https://api.jquery.com/on/

but I dont know how to use it :/

Comment: It is better to move scripts to the Script section and call this section in your layout. Possibly, it can also fix your problem

Comment: @Anton i layout my scripts don't work

Comment: What version of ASP.NET do you use?

Comment: I use .Net Core 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you evoke .html() to replace partial view content, you are actually replacing existing DOM elements with new one. As a result, event handlers attached to these elements are also removed and your code stops working.

You will have to re-assign event handlers. Use .on() function to do so. A better approach is to use delegated event handlers inside parent view. But you can achieve results with below trick.

Update your 'success' function as below,

```
$("#kartaEcp").html(data);

$( "#id_sb_year" ).on( "change", function() {
    pobierzTabele();
});

$( "#id_sb_month" ).on( "change", function() {
    pobierzTabele();
});
```

Comment: probably this way it works, for strange reasons it crashes. I will try another solution